# ADO.NET Data Services - format parameter - xml / json

Tags: .net, json, wcf-data-services

Has the $format parameter been removed with the VS2008 SP1 release of ADO.NET Data Services. I try to use it and I get the error:

> The query parameter '$format' begins with a system-reserved '$' character but is not recognized.

I think the support for the Atom stuff is very cool, but can you get "plain old xml" too?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my title. I must have been half-asleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now done via the http "Accept" header; use "application/json" for json. You could try "text/xml" for POX, but it isn't mentioned in the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc956153.aspx).

(update: text/xml will return atom, based on the table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx))

Comment: Wish they would have kept the $format variable for browser-based GET testing. Or provide some way to turn this back on. Guess I could pull out Reflector and have a go at it. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Pablo Castro has a clean solution: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP

It uses WCF behaviors to pick up $format=json

Answer (score 0):

This blog post shows how to make the $format=json work using the ASP.NET stack: http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/wcf-data-services-format-json/